# Login Error libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, objective-c

Whats happening is that every time I go to click my "Login button", the app crashes, it supposed to redirect the user to a different view where he can login with email and password. I tried many solutions in other posts but none of them seems to be working.
I am using `Sinch` SDK. In login process after getting response my app crashing. if wont i use below code in login section then `Sinch` will not work. so please help me on this

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.push registerUserNotificationSettings];
[appDelegate initSinchClient:[saveDefault objectForKey:@"emailId"]];
[appDelegate RegisterPushNotification];
```

thank you in adv

Comment: what the crash report

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException @Anubu

Comment: show the full crash

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException only this one is coming in crash report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use protocol delegate method for this

In Viewcontroller

```
@protocol LoginVCDelegate <NSObject>

@required -(void) didFinishLogin;

@end
@property (nonatomic,unsafe_unretained) id<LoginVCDelegate>delegate;

 if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishLogin)])

 {

     [self.delegate didFinishLogin];                   

}
```

In App Delegate

```
-(void) didFinishLogin
{
    [self.push registerUserNotificationSettings]; 

    [self initSinchClient:[saveDefault objectForKey:@"emailId"]];

   [self RegisterPushNotification];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.